# How to Represent Explicit Access Control i XACML 3.0

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, balana

We use XACML resource data labeling to provide access control to data. There are limits to what can/should be put in the data labels which use basic logic for each attribute type (anyinall or allinall).

There is a need to provide additional restrictions beyond the data labeling that can include **explicit lists of subjects that have access**. In this case, we want to extend the restrictions in the data labels with an explicit list of subjects (AND the data labeling permit to those in the list).

How would we write this in an XACML policy where (a) not only do we identify the subject but (b) can perform additional `resource.attributes` to `subject.attribute` comparisons.

We have used entitlements to represent membership in a "list", which is entitlement management intensive. The entitlement also has limited complex logic (e.g. combination of ANDs and ORs) of resources attributes to the subject id attributes.

Data labeling uses rules that include anyinall or allinall to bags of attributes (i.e. **resource.classification:"private"** **allinall subject.classification:"private"**)

I expect the Permit to include:

1. all data labels are permitted based on subject.attributes
2. the subjectID is included in a "list"
3. the subjectID meets complex logic comparisions of ANDs and ORs rules for resource.attributes to subjectID.attributes

Each section would permit or deny and any deny will fail the overall policy

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that in XACML (and ALFA - the more lightweight syntax of XACML). First of all, you stated that:

> Each section would permit or deny

To do so, you will use a Policy for each section that uses the `deny-unless-permit` combining algorithm. This means that either the policy will grant access if the conditions are met or it will deny access. You might remember that by default, if conditions are not met, the usual decision is `NotApplicable`. Using `deny-unless-permit` will prevent that.

> and any deny will fail the overall policy

Once you have written each policy using `deny-unless-permit`, you will combine them all into a parent policy set which will use a `deny-overrides` combining algorithm. This means that if there is any deny decision, then that decision will trump all other decisions.

This gives us the following structure:

### ALFA

```java
namespace com.axiomatics{
    /**
     * Resource data labeling to provide access control to data
     */
    policyset dataAccess{
        apply denyOverrides
        /**
         * First check
         */
        policy firstCheck{
            apply denyUnlessPermit
            /**
             * Allow if clearance is sufficient
             */
            rule clearanceCheck{
                permit
                condition com.acme.user.clearance > com.acme.record.classification
            }
            rule otherCheck{
                // Fill in your checks here
                permit
            }
        }
        /**
         * Second check...
         */
        policy secondCheck{
            apply denyUnlessPermit
        }
    }
}
```

### Equivalent in XACML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--This file was generated by the 
    ALFA Plugin for Eclipse from Axiomatics AB (http://www.axiomatics.com). --><!--Any modification to this file will 
    be lost upon recompilation of the source ALFA file -->
<xacml3:PolicySet
    PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides"
    PolicySetId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axiomatics.dataAccess"
    Version="1.0"
    xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
    <xacml3:Description>Resource data labeling to provide access control to
        data</xacml3:Description>
    <xacml3:PolicySetDefaults>
        <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116
        </xacml3:XPathVersion>
    </xacml3:PolicySetDefaults>
    <xacml3:Target />
    <xacml3:Policy
        PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axiomatics.dataAccess.firstCheck"
        RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-unless-permit"
        Version="1.0">
        <xacml3:Description>First check</xacml3:Description>
        <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
            <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116
            </xacml3:XPathVersion>
        </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:Target />
        <xacml3:Rule Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="com.axiomatics.dataAccess.firstCheck.clearanceCheck">
            <xacml3:Description>Allow if clearance is sufficient
            </xacml3:Description>
            <xacml3:Target />
            <xacml3:Condition>
                <xacml3:Apply
                    FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:any-of-any">
                    <xacml3:Function
                        FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:integer-greater-than" />
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                        AttributeId="com.acme.user.clearance"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
                        MustBePresent="false" />
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                        AttributeId="com.acme.record.classification"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
                        MustBePresent="false" />
                </xacml3:Apply>
            </xacml3:Condition>
        </xacml3:Rule>
        <xacml3:Rule Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="com.axiomatics.dataAccess.firstCheck.otherCheck">
            <xacml3:Description />
            <xacml3:Target />
        </xacml3:Rule>
    </xacml3:Policy>
    <xacml3:Policy
        PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axiomatics.dataAccess.secondCheck"
        RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-unless-permit"
        Version="1.0">
        <xacml3:Description>Second check...</xacml3:Description>
        <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
            <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116
            </xacml3:XPathVersion>
        </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:Target />
    </xacml3:Policy>
</xacml3:PolicySet>
```

### Other Checks

In addition to your policy structure, you mention that you would to control access based on attributes (e.g. a user can view a document they own) and also based on explicit access control (a user can view a document if they are on the list for that document). You can absolutely implement discretionary access control (DAC) in XACML in addition to attribute-based access. Here is an example:

```javascript
/**
 * Second check...
 */
policy secondCheck{
    target clause com.acme.action.actionId == "view" and com.acme.object.objectType == "document"
    apply denyUnlessPermit
    /**
     * Users can view documents they own
     */
     rule owner{
         permit
         condition com.acme.record.owner==user.userId
     }
     /**
      * Users in the whitelist can view the document
      */
     rule dac{
         permit
         condition stringAtLeastOneMemberOf(user.userId, com.acme.record.whitelist)
     }
}
```